# VHDL - (modelsim) - Fatal error that indicated during test bench at CASE

Tags: vhdl, fpga, modelsim

I am refreshing my **VHDL** programming skills (by using ModelSim), I wrote Shift register project and a test bench, I compiled both of them successfully.
when I tried to run the TB file, I got a Fatal error that related to CASE: shl(shift left)/Shr(shift right/rtl/rtr

Someone can help me to understand what the problem is?

```
Library ieee;
Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use work.New_Data_Pack.all;

Entity Shift_Reg IS
port(
    Clk,Rst :IN std_logic;
    Data :IN byte; -- std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    Sel :IN t_shift; --sample, shl, shr, rotl, rotr
    Q_out :OUT byte

);

End Shift_Reg;

ARCHITECTURE Shift_Reg_arc OF Shift_Reg IS
Signal ACC: byte:=(OTHERS=>'0'); -- std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
BEGIN

PROCESS (Clk,Rst)
BEGIN
    IF Rst='1' Then
        Q_out<=(OTHERS=>'0');
        ACC<=(OTHERS=>'0');
    ELSIF Clk'EVENT and Clk='1' THEN
        **CASE Sel is
            WHEN sample=>
                ACC<=Data;
            WHEN shl=>
                ACC<=ACC (6 downto 1) & '0'; -- & concatenation
            WHEN shr=>
                ACC<='0'&ACC(6 downto 1);
            WHEN rotl=>
                ACC<=ACC(6 downto 1)& ACC(7);
            WHEN rotr=>
                ACC<=ACC(0)&ACC(6 downto 1);**
        END CASE;

    END IF;
 
    Q_out<=ACC;

End PROCESS;
End Shift_Reg_arc;
```

thank you
Idan

Comment: Provide a [mcve], here the package New_Data_Pack apparently supplies declarations type t_shift, type byte, sample, shl, shr, rotl and rotr and the actual complete error text. It also isn't clear if the testbench source is required.

Comment: Removing the double asterisks added for emphasis, genning up a package declaration for new_data_pack containing an enumerated type declaration for t_shift with values shown  in the SEL declaration comment and a subtype byte declaration with a range from the comment in the ACC declaration demonstrates the need for the package declaration, testbench, and actual error message. Assignment to ACC with 8 elements of a waveform with 7 elements (e.g. `ACC(6 downto 1)& ACC(7)`) would result in a simulation error. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.3.4 Signal update para 2 b).

Comment: The Modelsim vsim error would be of the form `# ** Fatal: (vsim-3420) Array lengths do not match. Left is 8 (7 downto 0). Right is 7 (0 to 6).` They'd likely show up in order progressing to the next one  after fixing the current error. First line 30, the line 32, line 34 and line 36 corresponding to shl, shr, rotl, and rotr (the order is based on your testbench shown in your later question).

Answer (score 0):

Notice you have `**` before and after the case block.

Remove these:

```
**CASE Sel is
^^

ACC<=ACC(0)&ACC(6 downto 1);**
                            ^^
```

Comment: Syntax errors wouldn't be discovered running the testbench as the OP notes.